# pre-build script path not logging output

Tags: tfs, msbuild, npm, build-definition

I have a pre-build PowerShell script defined in my Build Definition. The PowerShell script execute a program:

```
& "c:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "run" "build"
```

When `npm` runs, npm writes things to stdout/console. This output doesn't show up in my logs for the build though.

What do I need to do to make sure the build logs capture this console output?

In other words, is there something I can add to `& "c:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "run" "build"` that will pipe the output to the build log?

EDIT:

I think it's one of these three but not sure which:

```
& "c:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "run" "build-release" 2>&1 | Out-Host
& "c:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "run" "build-release" 2>&1 | Write-Host
& "c:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" "run" "build-release" 2>&1 | Write-Output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set logging to verbose it will log everything...

I normally add a -Verbose at the end of every line